# MSCRM 2013 and SQL Server 2014 SP3

Tags: sql-server-2014, dynamics-crm-2013

Can CRM 2013 use SQL Server 2014 SP3?

This article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3005167/compatibility-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013

only mentions SP2....

Regards
 Alf

Comment: That document hasn't been updated in over 2 years; SP3 wasn't even out when that document was last updated.

Comment: Plus that document says "This article does not indicate Microsoft Dynamics CRM compatibility for all products" so... Hard to tell, I would suggest searching more documentation

Comment: Exactly why I asked the question, Larnu.